# In rails, how can I have a unique constraint on a has many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, has-many-through

I have the following:

```
class A < Active... 
  has_many :bs
  has_many :cs, through: :bs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cs
end
clas B < Active...
  belongs_to :a
  belongs_to :b
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cs
end
class C < Active... 
  has_many :bs
  has_many :as, through: :bs
end
```

I want to add a uniqueness constraint so that the sets of `A.cs` can never be duplicated. that is to say no two As can have the exact same set of Cs related to them. If this A exists:

```
A.first.cs.pluck(:key) => ['c1', 'c2']
```

then no other A can have ['c1', 'c2'] assigned to it until the first A is deleted or updated.

I can think of 2 ways, but is there a rails way:

1) Denormalize the `A` table adding a 'cs' column which holds a string of all the `Cs` associated to each `A` object, then put the constraint on that new 'cs' column.

2) Instanciate all existing `As` and compare each to the new `a`

The biggest problem is that creating `As` `Bs` and `Cs` at the same time using the nested_attributes_for as `a = A.create(bs_attributes:[{cs_attributes:{...}},{cs_attributes:{...}}])` won't populate `a.cs` until it has created `a` and at that time it is too late to do a callback for validation.

Answer (score 1):

In B, you can have

```
validates :c_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :a_id }
```

Comment: What you suggest only makes sure that no C is associated to an A more than once A.first.cs.pluck(:key) => ['c1','c1'] would be invalid. I'll update the question to make it clear that the validation should be on the set of cs any A has associated. Thanks :)